# Upload an image to android layout

Tags: android, image, android-layout, layout, image-uploading

When click "Button" button it will be able to browse images in my gallery folder and when i select an image it should be add to my layout.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Intent` to open gallery in `onClick`.

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
```

**Listen for the result**
Get the selected image in `onActivityResult`. Use `ImageView` to host the selected image.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri photoUri = data.getData();
        if (photoUri != null) {
            try {
                currentImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), photoUri);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(currentImage);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use ImageView. Please notice "I" in caps.

Answer (score 0):

when you call the gallery intent use startActivityForResult() and them you handle it inside onActivityResult()

Here is the link to the official documentation: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Answer (score 0):

**Inside your button's OnClickListener:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setType("image/*");  
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose an Image"), 0);
```

**Then, Override onActivityResult and do:**

```
URI uri = intent.getData()
```

Finally, call setImageURI(uri) from the imageview you want the picture to be in:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimageviewid);
iv.setImageURI(uri);
```